# GStrings in Python

Tags: python, gstring

Groovy has a concept of GStrings. I can write code like this:

```
def greeting = 'Hello World'
println """This is my first program ${greeting}"""
```

I can access the value of a variable from within the String.

How can I do this in Python?

--
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Python, you have to explicitely pass a dictionary of possible variables, you cannot access arbitrary "outside" variables from within a string. But, you can use the `locals()` function that returns a dictionary with all variables of the local scope.

For the actual replacement, there are many ways to do it (how unpythonic!):

```
greeting = "Hello World"

# Use this in versions prior to 2.6:
print("My first programm; %(greeting)s" % locals())

# Since Python 2.6, the recommended example is:
print("My first program; {greeting}".format(**locals()))

# Works in 2.x and 3.x:
from string import Template
print(Template("My first programm; $greeting").substitute(locals()))
```

Comment: Note that the parens with print are a 3.0 newness; before print was a keyword, in 3.0 it's just a function like any other, so it needs the parens. This is why you see examples without them, in other answers.

Comment: print("My first program; {greeting}".format(**locals()))

This last line gives me an error:

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'format'

Comment: That's because you're not on 3.0 - the last example is 3.0-only.  The preferred option in Python 2.x is the first example.

Comment: Ferdinand - please add Python version clarifications to your answer.  Python 2.x is still much more widely used than 3.0.

Comment: @Carl: Thanks for the comment. I added the version hint -- note that str.format() is actually available since 2.6.

Comment: Note that the s in %(greeting)s is for "string", not for making 'greeting' plural. ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
d = {'greeting': 'Hello World'}
print "This is my first program %(greeting)s" % d
```

Answer (score 2):

In Python 2.6+ you can do:

```
"My name is {0}".format('Fred')
```

Check out [PEP 3101](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/).

Answer (score 1):

You can't exactly...

I think the closest you can really get is using standard %-based substitution, e.g:

```
greeting = "Hello World"
print "This is my first program %s" % greeting
```

Having said that, there are some fancy new classes as of Python 2.6 which can do this in different ways: check out [the string documentation for 2.6](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html), specifically from section 8.1.2 onwards to find out more.

Answer (score 1):

If your trying to do templating you might want to look into Cheetah.  It lets you do exactly what your talking about, same syntax and all.

http://www.cheetahtemplate.org/